Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs con docker-compose build
Soy nuevo en Spring boot, estoy intentando crear una solución multi module project, donde tengo una arquitectura de carpetas asi:
microservices-project
->order-service
--> pom.xml
--> dockerfile
->product-service
--> pom.xml
--> dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
pom.xml

Y me esta dando un error al intentar correr en local docker-compose build, y al correr  mvn clean install funciona bien, qué está pasando, comparto los archivos pom de los dos hijos, del padre y los archivos dockerfile y docker-compose:
docker-compose.yml
services:
  order-service:
    build:
      context: ./order-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2 # Compartir repositorio Maven local para evitar duplicar dependencias
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"

  product-service:
    build:
      context: ./product-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2 # Compartir repositorio Maven local para evitar duplicar dependencias
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"

Parent pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>product-service</module>
        <module>order-service</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Common dependencies for all services -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>

Hijo DockerFile
# Usamos la imagen base con OpenJDK 21
FROM openjdk:21-jdk-slim AS builder

# Establecemos el directorio de trabajo
WORKDIR /app

# Copiar el POM del proyecto principal y el POM del servicio
COPY ../../pom.xml ../pom.xml
COPY pom.xml .

# Instalamos Maven
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven

# Instalamos las dependencias del proyecto
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests

# Copiamos el código fuente
COPY src ./src

# Empacamos la aplicación
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

# Imagen base para la aplicación en producción (con OpenJDK 21)
FROM openjdk:21-jdk-slim

# Directorio de trabajo en el contenedor
WORKDIR /app

# Copiamos el archivo JAR generado en el contenedor final
COPY --from=builder /app/target/*.jar app.jar

# Exponemos el puerto donde correrá el servicio
EXPOSE 8080

# Comando para ejecutar el servicio
CMD ["java", "-jar", "order-service.jar"]

Hijo pom ejemplo
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservices-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>order-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Order Service</name>
    <description>Order service for microservices project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar a ver que puede ser, ya intenté muchas soluciones y no di con la respuesta, ambos proyectos hijos los hice con Spring initializr, este es el error al correr docker-compose build :
[+] Building 7.3s (16/23)                                                                                       docker:desktop-linux
 => [product-service internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                            0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 953B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [order-service internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 950B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [product-service internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:21-jdk-slim                                          2.0s
 => [product-service internal] load .dockerignore                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [order-service internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [product-service internal] load build context                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring context: 840B                                                                                               0.0s
 => [order-service builder 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:21-jdk-slim@sha256:7072053847a8a05d7f3a14ebc778a90b38c50ce7e8f1  0.0s
 => CACHED [order-service builder 2/8] WORKDIR /app                                                                             0.0s
 => [order-service internal] load build context                                                                                 0.1s
 => => transferring context: 828B                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [product-service builder 3/8] COPY ../../pom.xml ../pom.xml                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [product-service builder 4/8] COPY pom.xml .                                                                         0.0s
 => CANCELED [product-service builder 5/8] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven                                       5.1s
 => CACHED [order-service builder 3/8] COPY ../../pom.xml ../pom.xml                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [order-service builder 4/8] COPY pom.xml .                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [order-service builder 5/8] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [order-service builder 6/8] RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests                                                         4.9s
------
 > [order-service builder 6/8] RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests:
4.662 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
4.735 [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
4.735 [WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM com.example:order-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/app/pom.xml) points at com.example:order-service instead of com.example:microservices-project, please verify your project structure @ line 7, column 10
4.735 [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:order-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example:microservices-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 10
4.735  @
4.738 [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
4.739 [ERROR]
4.739 [ERROR]   The project com.example:order-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/app/pom.xml) has 1 error
4.740 [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:order-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example:microservices-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 10 -> [Help 2]
4.741 [ERROR]
4.743 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
4.744 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
4.744 [ERROR]
4.745 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
4.745 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
4.746 [ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
4.752
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mvn clean install -DskipTests" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

